# I bought movies on iTunes before, and when I saw it on iTunes or Apple TV, and it asks me to purchase again?

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-store

Let's say I purchased 300 movies on iTunes, and then sometimes I browse the iTunes store to see if there are some new or movies I can purchase.  I would then see a movie, and iTunes says I can purchase it, but only that when I check my email searching by

```
<that movie name> itunes receipt
```

Then it shows that I have already purchased it before.  If I go to my movies Library tab, I can't find it there either.

Today I tried it on my MacBook Air, and then I checked my iPhone, and it is the same result: nothing found.

So I tend to communicate to iTunes support, wasting 15 minutes to get back a $4.99 or $9.99 movie.

This time, the online chat support said at first the purchased movie has an expiration date, so I have to repurchase the movie.  I asked her "why did I purchase a movie and it can expire?" And she searched and found the following.

#### One "Solution"

However, it seems more apparent that there is "one way" to solve it, which is to find a way on the UI of iTunes or Apple TV to go to

```
Account -> Purchased
```

and search for the movie.  Now the movie is found and you cannot just watch it, but **have to** download it to watch it.

This time, this movie happen to be a movie that is on Apple TV that is part of "Try it for free on Cinemax" on the iPhone, but doesn't show such line on the MacBook.  But both places asked me to buy it again.

So is that it?  Always follow this "trick" to solve it?  This problem has been happening for close to 10 years and still it is not fixed.  If it happens merely 5, 6 times every single year, it is enough to make it annoying.

Comment: I've heard of this happening before, something about Apple losing the rights to a movie.  But if they're still _selling_ it, that's very odd.  If it's ONLY available as part of a Channel/Promotion, then maybe they have lost the rights to it.  I've had something similar a couple times, and I've done just what you did, download the movie and it worked.

Comment: I bought it already, and now, it is available on a channel *as well as* available to purchase again...  why do I buy a movie and then it disappears and I have to buy one more time

Comment: Wish I had a better answer!  That is really annoying. It’s interesting that you said Apple support can fix it if you call, so clearly they agree that you do own the movie. My guess is still a licensing issue on their end, and the movie that you can see available to purchase now is slightly different (re-release version) or they lost the license to it, then required it, but that invalidated your purchase under the original license. Streaming all our music and HD TV is amazing, but I don’t  trust that Apple (or any company) will always be there; I always download a copy.